# JQuery AJAX interrupted 'error'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, interrupt

I have a `.php` script that takes very long to complete (anywhere from 30 to 160 seconds).

From a webpage I am able to run this script using the JQuery `$.ajax()` function. However, if I try to leave the page while the ajax request is in progress the function throws an error `'error'`, which I `alert()`.

I was wondering however if the `.php` script continues? Because for my case it doesn't really matter if the webpage doesn't receive the response, as long as the `.php` script doesnt stop halfway trough.

**So:** if an `$.ajax()` is interrupted, does that `.php` script finish non-the-less?

Comment: Add code to more clear the problem

Comment: If the task does not return any critical data to the user it may be better to run the job in a queue instead of blocking up your webserver's connections while it processes

Comment: the task returns an 'succes' json array. which when the browser receives it, makes it refresh the datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to let the script run after closing the connection:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

You might want to look into job queues if you have long running scripts which do background tasks.